Python Tkinter - How do I read the value of a selected ComboBox within classed frames?
I have put a ComboBox in my code, which works. However, I am trying to find a way to read the value of the ComboBox when the user selects an option.
I have also used classes to define each of my frames that appear, that way I can transition between windows.
I am pretty inexperienced with Tkinter and cannot wrap my head around the ComboBox.
Here is my code for the part where I need to use a ComboBox:

class EntryPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

        def gunvarselect():
            gunselected = (gunvar)
            print(gunselected)

        gunvar = tk.StringVar()
        gunselect =ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=gunvar)
        gunselect.bind(self, '<<ComboboxSelected>>', gunvarselect)
        gunselect['values'] = ('Pistols', 'Shotguns', 'Rifles', 'Sniper Rifles', 'Sub-machine Guns', 'Light-machine Guns')
        gunvarselect()
        gunselect.pack(side="left", expand="false", pady=20, padx=50)








        gunvar2 = tk.StringVar()
        gunselect2 = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=gunvar2)
        gunselect2['values'] = (
        'Pistols', 'Shotguns', 'Rifles', 'Sniper Rifles', 'Sub-machine Guns', 'Light-machine Guns')
        gunselect2.pack(side="right", expand="false", pady=20, padx=50)

I have tried to read the value through linking an event, however, I could not end up configuring it properly.
I also tried to read the value through just the textvariable, but I don't think that would be efficient.

Use gunvar.get() to get the selected value. Also gunvarselect() function should have an argument, the event object.


Define the gunvarselect function to take an event parameter:

This function retrieves the selected value from the gunvar StringVar and prints it.


Fixed the bind method call:

Change the incorrect self to the correct gunselect object, and correctly bound the <<ComboboxSelected>> event to the gunvarselect function.



Here is the simplified and corrected portion of your code:
class EntryPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

        def gunvarselect(event):
            gunselected = gunvar.get()
            print(gunselected)

        gunvar = tk.StringVar()
        gunselect = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=gunvar)
        gunselect['values'] = ('Pistols', 'Shotguns', 'Rifles', 'Sniper Rifles', 'Sub-machine Guns', 'Light-machine Guns')
        gunselect.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', gunvarselect)
        gunselect.pack(side="left", expand="false", pady=20, padx=50)

        gunvar2 = tk.StringVar()
        gunselect2 = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=gunvar2)
        gunselect2['values'] = (
        'Pistols', 'Shotguns', 'Rifles', 'Sniper Rifles', 'Sub-machine Guns', 'Light-machine Guns')
        gunselect2.pack(side="right", expand="false", pady=20, padx=50)


Would this work for a second ComboBox, as shown in gunvar2?

@Rubenith You should bind the event to gunvar2, then It will work too.

Sick! Thank you :D

Oh also, @Tanay, How would I go about binding this to an IF statement? I'm currently doing so, but i'm hit with syntax errors about not being bound to an event. I have tried giving it the parameter for an event, but still receive a similar syntax.
Let me know if you would like me to post the syntax error as a comment too.

@Rubenith Yeah, Post the syntax error.

Alright, so I added a part of code underneath the updated gunvar code from before:
if gunvarselect2() == 'Rifles':  subgunvar = tk.StringVar()  subgunselect = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=subgunvar)  subgunselect['values'] = ('Ak47', 'AUG', 'FAMAS', 'Galil AR', 'M4A4', 'M4A1-S', 'SG 553')  subgunselect.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', subgunvarselect)  subgunselect.pack()

Then comes the syntax error:
TypeError: EntryPage.__init__.<locals>.gunvarselect2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

@Rubenith Here's how you define a event function def gunvarselect2(event): . The event is necessary here.
